# Magento on Amazon ec2 and var /common files directory

Tags: magento, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, var

I want to put on EC2 a medium Magento Installation.

I have used a Load Balancer, CDN for images, RDS mysql.

But now I have to choose where and how save Magento files( `/app` and `/var` directory).

I Think that use the local EBS file system is better, and with GIT I don't have any problem to update the code. But i have a problem with the `/var` directory, in this I have a directory with many csv used for some integration with other system (that read it with an FTP).

How I can manage those files?

Answer (score 0):

I'm researching how to do something similar and so far this is what I'm exploring but won't be testing it for quite a while, maybe it can help you.

Sign up for Amazon S3. Install [Fuse over Amazon](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon). Create a bucket for each folder in S3. Map your /var and /media and whatever other directory to the appropriate bucket. You obviously won't want to store the xml cache that magento does since it will likely be kinda slow. You can mount s3 with a local cache -ouse_cache=/tmp which might be work playing around with.

You should report back if you figure something out.